# .Net Core 2.1 too slow network download file failure issue

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I use dot net core 2.1 and i wrote get rest file download api. But some servers pc's which are located at too slow network area sometimes 
make download failure. The detail situation is that, i download the file by get api (http) with chrome browser. Then download is start but it will fail in few minutes (1min~1.5min).

Any below is my code. (below works on normal network area but not on slow area)

```
[HttpGet("Download")]
public IActionResult Download(string filePath)
{
   byte[] fileData = null;
   System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, datum);

   string fileName = $"File.zip";
   Response.ContentLength = fileData.LongLength;
   return File(fileData, "application/octet-stream", fileName);
}
```

The file data size is just 20~25MB. I already searched solution to solve this.

1. Add requestTimeout="00:20:00" property in web.config
2. Set Content Length in download web api.

   Response.ContentLength = fileBinaries.LongLength;

But unfortunately all of these does not work for me.
Why does this problem cause and how should i gonna fix this?

Comment: Is there an error message when it fails?

Comment: In chrome file download tab has -network error log.

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to show us the code which sends the file?

Comment: Oh i'm sorry i edited it :)

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue?  If so, what was the solution?

Comment: @Ryan  It was too past. So, sorry to saying  "it's hard to remember by accurately". In my case, i had used Windows and IIS. And there is an IIS web.config option value to set request timeout. Try to check web.config option instead source code. It worked well.